# nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.server_name.co" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, certbot

I was already using nginx default configuration settings along with wsgi for flask deployment.

Now , I am trying to handle https requests on production server. For this had mapped IP to a domain(lets say www.server_name.co) and followed [how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) to do the necessary configuration as per.

While testing configuration using sudo nginx -t it gives following error.

```
ginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.server_name.co" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.server_name.co" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Followed various link related to this issue on stack overflow and also checked the default configuration  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and commended default server blocks and restarted the nginx server and tested again sudo nginx -t . Still it is giving same error.

Here is my configuration files of  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default  after adding configuration for www.server_name.co

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #   deny all;
        #}
    }


    # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
    #
    # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
    # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
    #
    #server {
    #   listen 80;
    #   listen [::]:80;
    #
    #   server_name example.com;
    #
    #   root /var/www/example.com;
    #   index index.html;
    #
    #   location / {
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #   }
    #}

    server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name www.server_name.co; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #   deny all;
        #}


        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.server_name.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.server_name.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


       }
```

Can anybody help me setup https nginx deployments? Any leads highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do you have another file in `sites-enabled` specifically for `server_name.co`?

Comment: @ShawnC. There are three files are there

ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-193:~$ ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/d
default     server_name.co  ds_backend

Comment: so it sounds like you declared port 80 in `default` and at least one of the other files. You should only have a unique `server_name` once per port.